# Check if a number is float or integer

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, floating-point, integer

I am making an IOS calculator app. I want to get if the division of two numbers will give a floating value or an int value. Can any body tell me how to get this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to know without actually computing a/b, check whether the remainder of a/b is null:

```
if (fmod(a,b) == 0) {
  // integer result
} else {
  // floating-point result
}
```

see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/

Answer (score 1):

If the [`floor()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math.h#Overview_of_functions) of a number is equal to that number, it is an integer.

However, beware of [floating-point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) [gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1458633/139010).

Comment: This method tests a single number, presumably the quotient. This means the quotient has already been calculated, which means the exact mathematical quotient has been rounded to floating-point, and you have lost information. The calculated result might be an integer even though the exact result is not. The accepted answer by Stéphane does not have this problem.

Comment: I agree, the accepted answer is _better_ than mine, though `fmod`'s arguments are floats as well, so there's no completely escaping the limitations of floating point.

Comment: For example, with double a=0.5,b=0.1; double c=a/b; c is 5.0 and floor(c)==c, though fmod(0.5,0.1) gives something near 0.1, not 0 (A decent libm shall provide a fmod which answer nearest floating point value). Both answers could match, it all depends if question was about exact division or floating point division...